# Oracle SQL Developer: Dynamic Selection of Rows Where Value in Column = MAX Value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, max

Please see example below to better understand my question:

Columns in table "Names":

[Table and Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frGCn.jpg)

Goal is to get the maximum Version per ID. Output should be:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClBGo.jpg)

What are the possible ways to achieve that? E.g. using self join on the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also your sample data image shows everything with ID 1, the output suggests the last two rows should have 2; and is the name always the same for all rows for an ID? You already know you need the max, which is an aggregate function, so what problems are you having trying to use that?

Comment: I have fixed the ID. It doesn't matter if same the ID has identical name, the version is different (also there might be more columns with differences, I have only added 3 columns for simplicity). My goal is to filter by MAX version per ID, and have only two output rows in this case.

Comment: It does matter. If the names are different then presumably you want to show the name corresponding to the maximum version? And the solution might be different if there are more columns.

Comment: You are correct. I only want the take columns which correspond to the maximum version per ID. Otherwise, I can use Group By function to only get information of what is the maximum ID.

Comment: Use row_number() or analytical max() like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1255). And please check for Oracle top-n queries on SO, this question was already answered thousands times.

Answer (score 0):

If the name for an ID is always the same then this is simple aggregation; with sample data as a CTE:

```
-- CTE for sample data - same names
with your_table (id, name, version) as (
            select 1, 'Name1', 1 from dual
  union all select 1, 'Name1', 2 from dual
  union all select 1, 'Name1', 3 from dual
  union all select 2, 'Name2', 1 from dual
  union all select 2, 'Name2', 2 from dual
)
-- actual query
select id,
  name,
  max(version) as version
from your_table
group by id, name
order by id;

        ID NAME     VERSION
---------- ----- ----------
         1 Name1          3
         2 Name2          2
```

If the name might be different and you want to see the name that corresponds to the maximum value for each ID then you can use the `last` function:

```
-- CTE for sample data - different names
with your_table (id, name, version) as (
            select 1, 'Name1', 1 from dual
  union all select 1, 'Name2', 2 from dual
  union all select 1, 'Name3', 3 from dual
  union all select 2, 'Name1', 1 from dual
  union all select 2, 'Name2', 2 from dual
)
-- actual query
select id,
  max(name) keep (dense_rank last order by version) as name,
  max(version) as version
from your_table
group by id
order by id;

        ID NAME     VERSION
---------- ----- ----------
         1 Name3          3
         2 Name2          2
```

You can also use a subquery to assign a ranking to each row, which might be more convenient if you have lots of columns to retrieve for the maximum version:

```
select id, name, version --, other columns
from (
  select id, name, version, -- other columns,
    rank() over (partition by id order by version desc) as rnk
  from your_table
)
where rnk = 1
order by id;

        ID NAME     VERSION
---------- ----- ----------
         1 Name3          3
         2 Name2          2
```

The `rank()` analytic functions adds a `rnk` column to the inline view's result set; the `partition by` and `order by` mean that the highest version for each ID is ranked 1, and the outer query then filters to only show those rows that are ranked 1.

This assumes the combination of ID and version is unique, which seems reasonable. If it isn't then you need to decide how to break ties.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole

The rank() analytic function does the job for my need.